# MessageBox must show element name not element type

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="430" Width="525">

<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="Button1" Content="Click Me" Width="90" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

    <ListView x:Name="ListView1" SelectionMode="Single" Margin="50">

        <ListViewItem>
            <StackPanel x:Name="THEME_1_">
                <Label Content="THEME 1"/>
                <TextBlock Background="#fff7bdbd"/>
                <TextBlock Background="#d0ff99"/>
                <TextBlock Background="#ffc378"/>
                <TextBlock Background="#fff593"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ListViewItem>

        <ListViewItem IsSelected="True">
            <StackPanel x:Name="THEME_2_">
                <Label Content="THEME 2"/>
                <TextBlock Background="#bca7dd"/>
                <TextBlock Background="#6dd8d6"/>
                <TextBlock Background="#e086e5"/>
                <TextBlock Background="#ffeab6b6"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ListViewItem>

        <ListViewItem>
            <StackPanel x:Name="THEME_3_">
                <Label Content="THEME 3"/>
                <TextBlock Background="#ffe9c1"/>
                <TextBlock Background="#d2b6d4"/>
                <TextBlock Background="#ebf2d4"/>
                <TextBlock Background="#f2b8b1"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ListViewItem>

    </ListView>
</Grid>

</Window>
```

vb.net

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each obj As Object In LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(CType(ListView1.SelectedItem, DependencyObject))
        MessageBox.Show(obj.ToString)
    Next
    End Sub
```

The codes above works great.

When you run the codes above and click Button1 you will see that the MessageBox shows you **System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel**

I want MessageBox shows me **StackPanel Name**.

Comment: You have to convert the elements to a type that has a name.  In XAML you can get the name because it's a dependency property of UIElement so there are other options.  ```object``` does not have a ```Name``` property and it's also not  ```DependencyObject```... You need to either iterate on a type or attempt converting the obj to the type you're expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, all you are doing in casting to an Object type, it doesn't have a `Name` property. What you need to do is check to see if the object is of the type `StackPanel` and then cast to that type to get access to its Name property

```
    For Each obj As Object In LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(CType(ListView1.SelectedItem, DependencyObject))
        If TypeOf obj Is StackPanel Then
            Dim stackPanel As StackPanel = CType(obj, StackPanel)
            MessageBox.Show(stackPanel.Name)
        End If
    Next
```